# Iterating through ArchiveInputStream or structures having a 'next'-accessor

Tags: kotlin

ArchiveInputStream is from apache-commons compress. it is an InputStream. `nextEntry`  is the only method for traversing the stream i've found the while loop is IDE converted from apache docs.

```
fun ArchiveInputStream.forEachEntry(doThis: (ArchiveEntry) -> Unit) {
    var e: ArchiveEntry?
    while (this.nextEntry.also { e = it } != null) {
        e?.let { doThis(it) }
    }
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to call next on an item until it is null and then use that in supplied function. It feels a bit weird to check if it's null and then to still have to use `e?.let` instead of just `doThis(e)`

full context of code

```
 Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(filePath)).use { fi ->
    BufferedInputStream(fi).use { bi ->
        GzipCompressorInputStream(bi).use { gzi ->
            TarArchiveInputStream(gzi).use { tarStream ->
                tarStream .forEachEntry {
                    // do things with entry and tarStream 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I rolled back your last edit. After getting an answer you are not allowed to change your code anymore. This is to ensure that answers do not get invalidated and have to hit a moving target. If you have changed your code you can either post it as an answer (if it would constitute a code review) or ask a new question with your changed code (linking back to this one as reference). See the section _What should I not do?_ on [_What should I do when someone answers my question?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for more information

Comment: I read the edit you made (and Sam is right). Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more idiomatic approach would be to transform your `ArchiveInputStream` to a `Sequence<ArchiveEntry>`, on which you can do things like `filter`, `map`, `forEach`...

As the only way you have of iterating through the input stream is `getNextEntry()`, we can write a method using a *sequence builder* to create the sequence.

```
fun ArchiveInputStream.asSequence(): Sequence<ArchiveEntry> {
    return sequence {
        var next = this.getNextEntry()
        while (next != null) {
            yield(next)
            next = this.getNextEntry()
        }
    }
}
```

Note that while Kotlin might suggest writing it as `this.nextEntry` (property accessor) I would recommend against it, as property accessors should be used for *properties* and not for methods with side-effects. (As `getNextEntry()` returns a different result each time, it has a side effect). The Java API for this class was clearly not written with Kotlin in mind.

With this `asSequence` function you can do this:

```
archiveInputStream.asSequence().forEach { ... }
```

---

Considering the full context of the code, you can reduce the nesting and amount of `.use` operations.

```
Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(filePath)).let {
    TarArchiveInputStream(GzipCompressorInputStream(BufferedInputStream(it)))
}.use { tarStream ->
    tarStream.forEachEntry {
        // do things with entry and tarStream 
    }
}
```

or if you want to split it up a bit:

```
Files.newInputStream(Paths.get(filePath))
    .let { BufferedInputStream(it) }
    .let { GzipCompressorInputStream(it) }
    .let { TarArchiveInputStream(it) }
    .use { tarStream ->
        tarStream.forEachEntry {
            // do things with entry and tarStream 
        }
    }
```

It's enough to close one of the streams as closing the decorating streams will also close the underlying stream.

Answer (score 0):

You basically created your own `forEach`.

More idiomatic way is to provide Iterator/Iterable interfaces. Then you can use built-in functions like `forEach`, `filter` and `map`.

Otherwise your implementation seems fine. Maybe I'd shorten your one liner to (I hope I get this right):

```
e?.let(::doThis)
```

Comment: Another alternative is `e?.also(::doThis)`, as `.let` is for returning a different value, while `.also` always returns the original value.

Comment: I totally agree about Iterator/Iterable, if it's possible to do in this data structure (unclear where the class comes from).

Comment: yes the intent is to get it to operate like those functions. i forgot i can look up the implementations to those functions and can compare to my solution.  thank you